# What is the difference beetwen "not" and "!" in Ruby except the precedence?

Tags: ruby, boolean-logic

I've have wrote a little exercise on Ruby. It is from [this](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-programming/building-blocks?ref=lc-pb) course. It shifts characters in the sting into n position. I get different results in my code here `if !char =~/\W/` depending on what I've used `!` or `not` keyword.
In first case it do not change string at all, in the second case it does. I can't get why. My Ruby version is 2.2. Here is my code:

```
def caesar_ciper(string, shift_factor)
    new_word = ""
    string = string.split(//)   #splits to char array
    string.each do |char|
        shift_factor.times do
            if !char =~/\W/ #char has to be a "word" character ONLY
                if char === "Z" #if it is last character go to first one
                    char = "A"
                elsif char === "z"
                    char = "a"
                else
                char = char.next #shift character
                end         
            end

        end
        new_word<<char
    end
    new_word
end

p caesar_ciper("What a 9 string!", 5)
```

UPD. I found this working better for me `if char =~/\w/ and char=~/\D/`, but still I it doesn't explain `not` and `!` difference.

Comment: Seems like the precedence might be important; why do you care about everything *except* that?

Comment: @Dave yup, that was the reason. There is an answer below.

Comment: Yes, I knew that was the answer. My point was that you were deliberately discounting what you already knew, and it wasn't clear to me why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already answered the question yourself: The difference is the precedence.

Ruby reads

```
if !char =~/\W/
```

as

```
if (!char) =~/\W/
```

What is obviously never true.

Where as:

```
if not char =~/\W/
```

is interpreted as

```
if !(char =~/\W/)
```